# Duplicate values in reference tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, innodb, database-normalization

Our application calls a stored procedure to normalize it's data to reference tables, after which it inserts a record into the main table partially containing values and partially containing ids that map to the reference tables. This is one of the stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_name`(IN valueIn varchar(100), OUT valueOut int)
BEGIN
declare maxid int;
declare countid int;
select max(id) into valueOut from tableName where fieldName=valueIn;
IF valueOut is NULL
THEN
  start transaction with consistent snapshot;
  select count(*) into countid from tableName where fieldName=valueIn;
  IF countid=0
  THEN
    insert into tableName (fieldName) values (valueIn);
    select  last_insert_id() into valueOut;
  ELSE
    select max(id) into valueOut from tableName where fieldName=ValueIn;
  end IF;
commit;
end IF;
END
```

When called manually this works fine but, when being called in production we end up with multiple duplicate values in the reference tables.

Transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ.

Ref table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Using a unique key constraint on the field fieldName isn't a good option. We have tried this but then instead of getting duplicate values, we see that the auto increment skips ID's. And we are trying to preserve ID's so that we do not need to over allocate when it comes to data types. Our main table is huge (multi billion) so we have to make efficient use of data types.

Anybody out there that understands this phenomenon?

Comment: *"Using a unique key constraint on the field fieldName isn't a good option."* It's a good option if values in that column are supposed to be unique.

Comment: What's the rest of "tableName" look like? The pasted code has a trailing comma . . .

Comment: This is just one of the ref tables.
The trailing comma was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of hurdles you have to clear if you want to build your own replacement for auto_increment. You'll find problems of serializability, concurrency, performance (usually related to locking), etc.

I think the simplest solution might be to use auto_increment on a column of type `bigint unsigned`. The maximum value of an unsigned integer is 4,294,967,295: roughly 4x10^9. The maximum value of an unsigned bigint is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615: roughly 1.8x10^19.

The auto_increment will still skip id numbers, but that's by design, and it shouldn't cause trouble with a range of 1.8x10^19.

Before you commit to this path, test big numbers with your client software. Some still don't deal gracefully with bigint, signed or not.

Comment: Hi Mike, Unfortunately this is not an option for us. The schema contains about 15 reference tables. These tables range from needing an unsigned TINYINT to at most an unsigned INT for their ID field. The main table referencing all of these tables is multi billion records large. If I were to make all the ID fields on the reference table a 64bit BIGINT I would also have to do this for all 15 fields on the main table containing the IDs to the reference tables. This would make my main table records too wide.

Comment: Then use TINYINT or SMALLINT as needed for the unique keys in the small (reference) tables. You don't have to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` but if you want to enforce uniqueness, make them unique. And deal with the (rare) errors from attempts to insert duplicate keys in the reference tables.